# SQL conditional in where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hi I have in my where clause the following condition:

```
and ( ( datepart(mm,cs.scheduledate) <= @month and @accumulate = 1 )
   or ( datepart(mm,cs.scheduledate) = @month and @accumulate = 0 ) )
```

So when `@accumulate = 1` I want to filter `datepart(mm,cs.scheduledate) <= @month` and if I have `@accumulate = 0` then want to filter by `datepart(mm,cs.scheduledate) = @month`

Im doing something wrong because its always filtering by `datepart(mm,cs.scheduledate) = @month`

Any clue?

Comment: It would seem that `@accumulate` always has a value of 0.

Comment: Before and .... any condition ?

Comment: for sure there must be something different. i just tried to reproduce it - see my rextester here - its working. http://rextester.com/EKLH57792

Comment: Without a script that reproduces the problem, I have to assume that your data isn't what you think it is.

Comment: Like Gordon said, the posted could should and will work correctly - so the real question is why @accumulate always has a value of 0.  Perhaps a logical error elsewhere in your code (if you're expecting mixed results)?

Comment: [Bad Habits to Kick : Using shorthand with date/time operations - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations)

Comment: +1 @SqlZim - especially because he doesn't seem to factor in the year (at least not in the posted code), so February 2016 would evaluate as BEFORE the current month (June 2017), while September 2016 would NOT.  Aside from strange circumstances, this type of evaluation is practically never needed, so I'm assuming it's a logical error.

Answer (score 0):

It's not fully clear to me what you're asking, but I have some ideas to try:

```
and ( ( datepart(mm,cs.scheduledate) < @month and @accumulate = 1 )
   or ( datepart(mm,cs.scheduledate) = @month and @accumulate IN (0,1) ) )
```

or

```
and 1 = CASE WHEN datepart(mm,cs.scheduledate)  = @month and @accumulate = 0 THEN 1
             WHEN datepart(mm,cs.scheduledate) <= @month and @accumulate = 1 THEN 1 
             ELSE 0 END
```